# Passing Params From Aspx

Tags: asp.net

So I had have a table populating with data but I was wondering how I could pass two bits of data from a row depending on which `link` at the end of the row is clicked.

```
<%WebReceiptSummary[] receipts = GetReceipts();
          if (receipts != null)
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < receipts.Length; i++)
              {%>
        <tr>
            <td><%= receipts[i].Type%></td>
            <td><%= receipts[i].PolicyNo%></td>
            <td><%= receipts[i].Date%></td>
            <td class="c"><%= receipts[i].Amount%></td>
            <td class="r"><asp:LinkButton OnCommand="PDFLinkClick" 
CommandArgument="<%= receipts[i].PDF %>&<% receipts[i].PolicyNo %>" runat="server">View PDF</asp:LinkButton></td>
        </tr>
        <% }
        }
        %>
```

Obviously my `CommandArgument` just passes back the string `<%= receipts[i].PDF %>&<% receipts[i].PolicyNo %>` not the values. What would be the best way of doing this? I was also thinking of using;

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenIsCaptchaReadyValidate" runat="server" Value=false/>
```

But I have the same problem here where the `value` is placed within quotes and also it means I need to create two `hiddenfields` for ever row which isn't the most efficient way of doing this. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have `<%= %>` commands as part of an attribute *when added via the mark-up*.

Can I recommend that instead of using the `for` loop in the ASPX, you instead use the `<asp:Repeater>` control?  This will also allow you to set the `CommandAttribute` value from the code-behind.

An example...

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="receipts" OnItemDataBound="receipts_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%#((WebReceiptSummary)Container.DataItem).Type%></td>
        <td><%#((WebReceiptSummary)Container.DataItem).PolicyNo%></td>
        <td><%#((WebReceiptSummary)Container.DataItem).Date%></td>
        <td class="c"><%#((WebReceiptSummary)Container.DataItem).Amount%></td>
        <td class="r"><asp:LinkButton ID="pdfLink" OnCommand="PDFLinkClick" runat="server">View PDF</asp:LinkButton></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In your Init or Load in code behind...

```
receipts.DataSource = GetReceipts();
receipts.DataBind();
```

Then...

```
protected void receipts_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("pdfLink")).CommandArgument = 
    ((WebReceiptSummary)e.DataItem).PDF + ((WebReceiptSummary)e.DataItem).PolicyNo;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thinking about it, rather than using the code-behind setting of the `CommandArgument`, I *think* (I haven't tested this yet) you could actually do the following without needing the `receipts_ItemDataBound` function...

```
 <td class="r"><asp:LinkButton ID="pdfLink" OnCommand="PDFLinkClick" runat="server"
   CommandArgument="<%#((WebReceiptSummary)Container.DataItem).PDF + ((WebReceiptSummary)Container.DataItem).PolicyNo%>"
   >View PDF</asp:LinkButton></td>
```

**UPDATE 2**

All instances of `Container.DataItem` in the above examples, have been changed into the tight-bound `((WebReceiptSummary)Container.DataItem)`

Comment: Hmm looks good but my `Container.DataItem` doesn't have any of those properties. Should I be converting my `WebReceiptSummary[]` somewhere?

Comment: The `Container.DataItem` should be an individual WebReceiptSummary object... basically, a single item of whatever the collection passed to `DataSource` contains.  As it's late binding, the properties won't appear through intelisense, but run it and it should be there.  I've also had a thought about the `CommandAttribute` thing... I will update my answer

Comment: Hmm trying your update but I'm getting errors in my `aspx` that dataitem doesn't recognise those properties. Won't build so I can't run it.

Comment: @killianmcc, really? I wasn't aware that code in ASPX was compiled in thatway. I would like to take this into a "chat room", but I haven't been offered the option yet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13804/discussion-between-freefaller-and-killianmcc)

Comment: @killianmcc, ah, my bad... I'm used to VB.NET, so I thought C# would work in the same way... have updated my example for you